# Java @RunWith not runnable in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The following Java class wasn't runnable in my IDE (Intellij IDEA). No reason was given by the IDE, which made troubleshooting painful and difficult.

The class looks like this:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions
class AcceptanceTests {
}
```

Comment: Hi, just wondering how this question is off topic? It's neither non-reproducable nor a typographical error - so the provided reason doesn't make sense. Thanks!

Comment: I agree... should definitely be opened. I added my vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution:** The `public` access level modifier was required on the class.

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions
public class AcceptanceTests {
}
```